# Mathematical Analysis Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3,...$ be Cauchy sequences in $[0,\infty)$, and let $c_n = a_n^2+\sqrt{b_n} + \sin(a_n+b_n)$. Prove that $c_1,c_2,c_3,...$ is also a Cauchy sequence by using the fact that a sequence of real numbers is a Cauchy sequence if and only if it converges.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I'm voting to close this question  because you show no work of your own. Please edit it to tell us what you tried and where you are stuck. Then perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 2):

Since the sequences $(a_n),(b_n)$ are Cauchy sequences, they converge.

Suppose $(a_n)$ converges to $A$, and $(b_n)$ converges to $B$.

Since $b_n \ge 0$ for all $n$, it follows that $B \ge 0$.

Since the functions $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto \sin(x)$ are continuous, and the function $x\to\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on the interval $[0,\infty)$, it follows that

- $(a_n^2)$ converges to $A^2$.$\\[4pt]$

  $(\sqrt{b_n})$ converges to $\sqrt{B}$.$\\[4pt]$

  $(a_n+b_n)$ converges to $A+B$, hence $\bigl(\sin(a_n+b_n)\bigr)$ converges to $\sin(A+B)$

It follows that $(c_n)$ converges to $A^2+\sqrt{B}+\sin(A+B)$.

Hence, since the sequence $(c_n)$ converges, it's a Cauchy sequence.